# Ancient art of war Flash game?

Tags: dos

I used to play [this game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ancient_Art_of_War) years ago on a DOS machine.  I was just wondering if anyone had come across it as a flash game...

Comment: Flash game on a Dos box? Are you sure?

Comment: As in remade as a flash game. Like Mario Brothers remade as a flash game so you can play it online...  http://www.2flashgames.com/play/f-Flash-Mario-Bros-1771.htm  Did your confusion really warrant a down vote?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: http://www.vizzed.com/vizzedboard/retro/game.php?id=5319

Comment: Have you been able to get this to work?  When I try to play it a bunch of gibberish comes up on the screen...